# Replicating minidlna files.db to another server

Tags: linux, dlna

Problem is following :

- there is a minidlna server(linux), files are located on hdd, inotify also works, perfect
- there is another server(linux), access to same folders/files via samba, minidlna is working, but inotify doesn't, not the same network. BTW perfect, but new music or film not detected.

Is there any way to replicate files.db? I've tried copying it, didn't work.
To rescan the full path again on the non-working part, it needs a lot of time, and I would like to avoid it.
Or is there a simple way to edit/modify/fix the original one?

Could somebody give me an idea how to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While editing `files.db` with `sqlitebrowser`, I noticed the path in some tables were totally different on server A and server B.

After changing server B to the same directory structure, I copied files.db from server A to server B. No more scan is needed on server B!

Now on server A if new film or new mp3 files is recognized and added to the database, it is suffice to transfer only the new files.db to server B.